# carrierwave doesn't render, path exists but image doesn't show up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

ive been trying to render a picture from carrierwave. i believe it is uploaded correctly because when i view the page source, i see

```
<img alt="Photo_44" src="/uploads/user/image/59/Photo_44.jpg" />
```

however by clicking on that src url, i get

```
No route matches [GET] "/uploads/user/image/59/Photo_44.jpg"
```

im using the default settings for carrierwave. the image does correctly get uploaded to my image column in my users table and locally, the path

sasha/Desktop/rails_projects/myproject/public/uploads/user/image/59/Photo_44.jpg

exists as well. however it won't display correctly. ive been following the railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads?autoplay=true

and reading

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave

but i cant seem to figure out what is wrong. where i upload the image is here

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), 
            :html => { :method => :put, :multipart => true }) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <%= render '/shared/fields', object: f.object, f: f %>
    <%= f.submit "Save changes", :class => "btn btn-large btn-primary", :style =>"display:block;" %>
    <div class="edit_avatar" >
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

and im trying to render it by...

```
<%= image_tag @user.image_url.to_s %>
```

what am i doing wrong?
help would be appreciated = )
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try set `config.serve_static_assets = true` if you haven't yet, should help.

Comment: oh man, i set it to false because when i set that to true, it totally messes up my jquery/bootstrap loading. i get this bizarre jquery/bootstrap issue when i set it to true. could you think of any other solution?

Comment: in production though, it should be set to false anyway right? so it would probably mess up in production then too right?

Comment: gosh, setting it to true does fix it. but it'll stop my bootstrap from working again

Comment: Yeah, it should be set to false in production, and static files should be served by your web server (nginx, apache) but this is good place to start debug it. Set your web server to serve files from public directory in your rails app and everything should be fine.

Comment: do you have to explicitly set the web server to serve the static files? im reading on heroku and they recommend using thin

Comment: I've never used heroku, because I have my own dedicated servers, so I'm afraid I can't help you, but AFAIR heroku have great documentation so you should find what you're looking for