# Rails 3. Carrierwave uploaded images aren't displayed in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm uploading Carrierwave images to the app/assets/images directory. To display them, I do this...

```
 <%= image_tag "/assets/#{File.basename(@user.image_url(:thumb).to_s)}" %>
```

The resulting HTML is `<img src="/assets/thumb_1_1_leonel.jpg">`
It works perfectly in development, NOT in production. The image is in fact, uploaded.

The permissions of the images uploaded are `-rw-r--r--`.

I already tried setting `config.serve_static_assets` to true (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612914/carrierwave-doesnt-render-path-exists-but-image-doesnt-show-up), then restarted Unicorn and ngnix, but I saw no change.

Why aren't they displayed?

Comment: are you storing them in different folders/filenames per environment? check your store_dir method in carrierwave

Comment: No, this is all I have in my store_dir method `Rails.root + "app/assets/images"`

Comment: I just gave 777 permissions to the jpgs that aren't being displayed, it didn't fix anything.

Comment: all you should need for carrierwave is  <%= image_tag @user.image_url(:thumb).to_s %> , it stores the correct path in your database

Comment: If I do that, it displays the whole system path and I got no image showing in the page `<img src="/home/deployer/apps/myappname/releases/20120814163621/app/assets/images/the-image-that-doesnt-display.jpg">`

Comment: You shouldn't be storing uploaded files in your assets folder in production, that is for static files. Change your store_dir to 'public/my/upload/directory'

Comment: The files are not supposed to be public. Where else can I upload them to?

Comment: If you dont want the images to be public then you will have to do some more work, check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089933/showing-images-with-carrierwave-in-rails-3-1-in-a-private-store-folder

Comment: If we store it out side the application folder then what we have to do?

Answer (score 1):

add this in  production.rb

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: From the question: *"I already tried setting config.serve_static_assets to true "*.

Comment: config.serve_static_assets = true is deprecated, but thank you for the hint.  I used config.serve_static_files = true to fix the problem.